# Get n items in django model using releverse relationship

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

Is possible to get the last n items in the Django model, using the reverse relationship.

```
 {% for brand in brands %}

     {% for product in brand.product_set.all %}

     {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

I am tried in this way, But it prints all things. But want only last 3 items

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|slice`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#slice) to *slice* the collection with:

```
{% for brand in brands %}
    {% for product in brand.product_set.reverse|slice:":3" %}
        …
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```